# Can't see components in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, textarea, jscrollpane

I'm using a JScrollPane to hold a JTextArea for a large area of text. I add the TextArea directly to the JFrame, it works fine. But I add it to the scrollpane and add the scrollpane, I don't see the textarea. Here's my SSCCE:

```
public class foo extends JFrame{
    //gui elements
JTextArea chatMonitor = new JTextArea();

JScrollPane textPane = new JScrollPane();

ChatFrame(final String nickname, final String login, final String server, final String channel){
    setSize(500,500);
    chatMonitor.setEditable(false);
    chatMonitor.setVisible(true);
    textPane.add(chatMonitor);
    textPane.setAutoscrolls(true);
    textPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    textPane.setVisible(true);
    add(textPane);
}
}
```

Comment: Short, yes. Self Contained, no. Correct (Compilable), no. Example, hard to tell if that counts as an example or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `textPane` is a `JScrollPane`, you should never be adding components to it.

Instead use [`JScrollPane#setViewportView(Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportView%28java.awt.Component%29)

`JScrollPane` is made of a number components which work together to provide you the functionality required to make the component scrollable...

[image]

`JScrollPane` has a `JViewport`, which is used to contain the component you want to be scrolled.  You need to "apply" the component to the view.

Take a closer look at [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: Scroll panes are an exception to the rule when it comes the Swing container API, lots of people stumble over this problem ;)